# Why isn't my Apps Documents folder visible?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

for my iOS app i want my users to store files in the apps document folder. But it isn't visible on install. I've set both `UIFileSharingEnabled` and `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` to `true` but the folder isn't visible. 
I've followed these exact steps described [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/working-with-the-files-app-in-ios-11/).

this is how it should be

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I tried following [this tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/files-app-integration/), writing a document to the documents directory (see code below), ensuring that both `UIFileSharingEnabled` and `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` were enabled, but still I was not seeing my App's folder in the File Browser.

It worked in the simulator, but not on a device.

Turns out the fix was to **restart the device**.

This was running 13.3.1.

**Update**: Other times even after a restart it would require hitting the back "Locations" button, and then "On My iPad" to refresh the list.

---

```
func createFileInDocumentsDirectory() {
    let file = "test.txt"
    let text = "Hello world"

    let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)
    try! text.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
}
```

Comment: It really sucks that you have to restart the device for this to work. Wish there was a workaround for this.

Comment: Oh, boy! More time down the drain. I guess iOS cashes the app settings or something. If that's true, probably deleting the app and reinstalling would work just as well as restarting the device. I hadn't tried either of these options, but restarting the device fixed it.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I've wasted days trying to figure out why this wasn't working for me, but this is what fixed it in the end. I went a step further and erased all content and settings on the device and it fixed some performance issues I was having too!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue with a document-based iOS app where I couldn't save or open documents on the device. The problem was that I had never created a document on the iPad I was using so the On My iPad location wasn't available.

The fix was to create a document in one of Apple's iWork apps and copy the document from iCloud to the device. After creating a document on the device, I was able to save and open documents in my app.

Comment: This helped me! on launch i create a file in the documents folder if there isn't already. because there is a file the folder is visible to the user!